# How to call confetti only once

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
if (isApplied && moreCount === 0 && route !== cartUrl && bagCouponActive) {
    return (
      <StickyBottomFooter bottom={bottomPosition}>
        <Confetti fire />
        <FlexBox
          spacing="py24 m-py12"
          align="center"
          justify="center"
          position="row"
          fullWidth
          style={{
            background: 'var(--secondary-green)',
            height: isMobile ? '40px' : '56px',
          }}
        >
          <Text size="16_24" mobileSize="14" thickness="medium" color="white">
            Congrats! you’ve unlocked '{couponCode}' offer
          </Text>
```

I am using Confetti to show this but appears everytime in every refresh these need to be get call only once in the home page

Answer (score 0):

If you mean only once and keep it through refreshes, you need to store somewhere information that your confetti fired, for example in localStorage/sessionStorage:

```
localStorage.set('fired',true)
```

and then just check if it was fired before

```
<Confetti fire={localStorage.get('fired')} />
```

If you want to reset this state on page refresh and keep it only though router changes and redirects, just keep this information in `useState` or `Redux store`

Comment: Dont need to use of localStorage here and it only come once not with refreshes